# Matching web page to word processor with CSS

Tags: html, css, margins

I'm trying to match the dimensions, margins, text sizes, line height, etc of a web page to those of a word processor (in this case, OpenOffice) so that when you go to print the web page or make a PDF of it, it will look exactly like the document.

So far I've set the height and width to 11in/8.5in, every side margin to 0.79in, and the font is the same size as the document. (That is, if documents use pt.)

So how come it's only taking up half the page??

This site is made to be printed/PDF'd, so it doesn't have to use flexible values.

Thanks!

Here is a link to a sample document, I'll have some code soon
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2Dl1.png

```
/*The rules go here*/
            #page-container {
                background: blue;
margin: 0.79in 0.79in 0.79in 0.79;
                width: 7.5in;
                height: 11in;
            }
            .name {
                font-size:22pt;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            .sections {
                margin: 10px 0 0 0;
                font-weight:bold;
                text-decoration:underline;
                clear:right;
            }
            .jobtitles {
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            .leftside {
                float:left;
            }
            .rightside {
                float:right;
                width:50%;
            }
            .years {
                float: right;
                font-weight:bold;
                padding-right: 1%;
            }
            .desc {
                width: 760px;
            }
            ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
            }
            #footer {
                text-align: center;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
```

The only reason its blue is so I can see the container.

Comment: What are the printing settings like? Are you zoomed out? Also, 8.5"x11" with a 0.79" margin if implemented literally will be too wide (i.e. the margins will be added to the dimensions).

Comment: Post code and a link to a sample document.

Comment: There you go. And the printing settings are just default as far as I know.